# Climate change ocean warming

Tags: thermodynamics

Can we convert and or create submarines to cool the oceans like a large ice cube.
This is outside the norm yet how we once had ice beakers can we create Ice subs and tankers. These tankers can be hospitals and water filtration, self significant systems. Provide assistance where needed like in the Philippines. These vessels can be powered through wave and motion technology combined with solar.

Comment: VTC as engineering

Comment: Where do you propose the heat you extract should go?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say no. You can imagine creating a huge fleet of cooling submarines, but the heat they subtract from the oceans has to go somewhere. Even worse, subtracting heat requires work, and this work produces additional heat. Moving around also creates heat. You'd have to dissipate all that heat out of our atmosphere to actually cool the oceans and we all know that heat is quite difficult to contain for a long period.

On a smaller scale, this is the same reason why you need to put part of the air conditioning system outside of your house. Otherwise you'd just end up warming your house even more.

Answer (score 0):

The Ocean is a vast heat energy resource - so removing some of  to supplement the energy required to power the submarine or ships engine would be ideal!!!. However to take advantage of this energy resource , on the scale of  a vessel's  power requirements,  it would require a very  substaintial heat pump and a very large assotiated heat absorbing element which could be attached to the  vessel's hull. I think it would be difficult to find a way of using the harvested heat to supplement a ships engine directly because of the temperatures involved.  There may be some fuel saving  advantage for  cruise ships by suplementing  the vessel's heating system  for the passengers or other low temperature  applications. There is little possibility of powering the vessel directly and only  from the heat in the ocean - and stop worrying about global warming  we should not interviene in the  natural processes involved with the climate - man made or otherwise. Despite what you have been told or believe any honest scientist will tell you that we simply do not understand enough about the climates natural control system to start making adjustments to it. We lave a lot of heavily funded so called "science" and a lot of opinions of the climate scientists - but very little in the way of  prediction or  repeatabilty - ie no "hard" science on which  to act with.